# Get contents of a changing DIV with static ID

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make myself a homepage, for my personal use only and what I want to do is to display different information from different websites that change few times a day. i.e. News, weather and such. I want to have my favorite information always on sight without the need to visit many pages. As many of websites don't load within an iframe which was the first thing I tried I figured PHP might be able to help me.

So what I need to do to is to get the contents of a DIV and place it within my page with PHP.
The DIV on the source page is generated on the server but it always have the same ID.

example:

```
<div id="nowbox"> 
<a href="http://www.seznam.cz/jsTitleExecute?id=91&h=19331020">
<img width="135" height="77" src="http://seznam.cz/favicons/title//009/91-JrAEVc.jpg" alt="" /></a> 
<div class="cont"> <ul> <li> 
<strong><a href="http://www.seznam.cz/jsTitleExecute?id=91&h=19331020">Sledujte dnes od 20.00 koncert Tata Bojs</a></strong> 
<p>Nenechte si ujít tradiční benefiční koncert kapely Tata Bojs. Sledujte představení na Seznam.cz</p> </li> </ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

so the ID of the DIV is "nowbox" and I need to copy all that is within it and put it in my page.

So far I was only able to use this

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://seznam.cz");
```

and view all contents of the page but I have no idea how to strip everything and leave only the needed DIV.

I am not very experienced in PHP so I would be very grateful for any help, the easier to understand the better.

EDIT:
THX for answers. Basically I just wanted to get the code I posted as example to a variable so I could ECHO it somewhere on my page. The problem is that the code changes as does the rest of the website and only some things remain the same i.e. the DIV ID.
Definitely NOT the most elegant solution (even I know that but as the website is for my purposes only it shouldn't matter) but one that I successfully managed to get to work is that I got the whole page with:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://seznam.cz");
```

and then counted the number of chars to a specific unique position in the code with STRPOS plus/minus a static number of characters that I could count manually. Then I split the string into ARRAYs and discard the parts I don't need to get the beginning of the code in the beginning of a string and then use the same method to cut the string after the code ended.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to fully understand what you want to achieve and why, but you can do this both through the server and client, first, the client side way:

Well, what you're asking is for is to extract parts of the DOM, using javascript + jQuery on the client side you can achieve it this very rapidly, simply by calling the `$.load("/mypage #nowbox")` function.

This could be achieved on the server side aswell using php by using any DOM manipulation library, either one that is bundled within ([DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) or one the easier to use libs (which is a bit memory leakish), [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

So there you have it, options for both client & server ways to implement, select which one suites your needs best.

please notice that any CSS ruling will not be available by either method, as the css won't be loaded in your dom.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this server side, I suggest you to use [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

```
require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');    
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentFileXHTML('http://seznam.cz');
$html = pq('#nowbox')->htmlOuter();
```